# Dafny: Why is this assertion failing and how to fix it

Tags: verification, formal-verification, dafny

Trying to prove a simple algorithm on Dafny, but I just get an "assertion violation" on the last assertion with no extra details. Can anybody spot what is wrong and how to fix it? Formal methods is not my specialty.

```
method  BubbleSort(a: array?<int>)
    modifies a
    requires a != null
    ensures sorted(a, 0, a.Length -1)
{
    var i := a.Length  - 1;
    while(i > 0)
        decreases i
        invariant i < 0 ==> a.Length == 0
        invariant -1 <= i < a.Length
        invariant sorted(a, i, a.Length -1)
        invariant partitioned(a, i)
    {
        var j := 0;
        while(j < i)
            decreases i - j
            invariant 0 < i < a.Length && 0 <= j <= i
            invariant sorted(a, i, a.Length -1)
            invariant partitioned(a, i)
            invariant forall k :: 0 <= k <= j ==> a[k] <= a[j]
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                a[j], a[j+1] := a[j+1], a[j];
            }
            j := j + 1;
        }
        i := i - 1;
    }
}

predicate sorted(a: array?<int>, l: int , u: int)
    reads a //Sintaxe do Dafny. PRECISA disso para dizer que vai ler o array
    requires a != null
{
    forall i, j :: 0 <= l <= i <= j <= u < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]
}

predicate partitioned(a: array?<int>, i: int)
    reads a
    requires a != null
{
    forall k, k' :: 0 <= k <= i < k' < a.Length ==> a[k] <= a[k']
}

method testSort()
{
  var b := new int[2];
  b[0], b[1] := 2, 1;
  assert b[0] == 2 && b[1] == 1;
  BubbleSort(b);
  assert b[0] == 1 && b[1] == 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the postcondition (`ensures` clause) of `Sort` gives no information about the state of `A`. When Dafny does verification, it verifies each method independently, using only the specifications (not the bodies) of other methods. So when Dafny verifies `testSort`, it doesn't look at the definition of `Sort`, but only its postcondition `true`, which isn't enough to prove your assertions.

For more information, see the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/wiki/FAQ#my-program-is-correct-but-dafny-says-there-is-a-problem-what-gives) and the section on assertions in the [tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Guide).

Comment: Thanks @James! I edited my code with a narrow postcontition, but still have an "assertion failed". Can you spot what is wrong?